# How can enabling CLR in one instance break something in another?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

So there's this company that has been working with SQL Server 2008 and for a project i needed some new features so i installed SQL Server 2012 express (both on the same server).
Months later, i had to use CLR for some complex operation so i enabled it there (2012):

```
sp_configure 'clr enabled', 1
```

Everything worked fine with CLR, but now they claim that since i enabled it they can't make backups on the 2008 database.
They don't do it normally, there's a 3rd party ERP that does the backups for them, and they say that when they try to backup, it just hangs up.
Disabling CLR makes them work again.

I kind of really need to have CLR enabled, and i simply don't understand how can having it enabled prevent doing something on another instance. If it was the other way around, that would make sense (disabling it).

Do any of you have any clue of what that 3rd party is doing that doesn't work with CLR enabled?

Comment: No idea.  But I would ask them to verify that backups work if they switch 'clr enabled' back off on the 2012 instance.

Comment: You are not being clear about where you enabled SQLCLR. Was it on just one instance or both? If on just one, please be clear about which one. The implication is that it was at least on 2012, and there is the implication that perhaps it was _not_ enabled on the 2008 instance, but it needs to be clearer. Also, did you enable SQLCLR immediately upon installing 2012 Express? Or was 2012 on that same server for a bit before enabling SQLCLR? I am wondering if the backup problem started upon enabling SQLCLR (unlikely), or upon installing 2012 (more likely since it also installs a newer .NET version).

Comment: They work again after disabling it.

It was on the 2012 one, at least that's where i ran the command (i heard CLR enables server wide, but i'm not sure). And no, it wasn't after installing, it is exactly after enabling that the problem presents, as disabling it makes everything work again.

Comment: I think you would be more likely to get an answer at [dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: There _shouldn't_ be any connection between any of those things, especially between two different instances. Enabling SQLCLR being "server-wide" really means "instance-wide", since the terms "server" and "instance" are (quite unfortunately) used interchangeably within SQL Server. The only stated conflict between SQLCLR and other stuff (that I am aware of) is with using "windows fibers (lightweight pooling)". But again, that shouldn't have _any_ effect between instances. So, maybe the backup software is trying to connect to the 2012 instance for some reason? what does the 2008 error log show?

Comment: ALSO, it should be noted that: **1)** SQL Server 2008 uses CLR 2.0 while SQL Server 2012 uses CLR 4.0, **2)** SQL Server's CLR host should be fully isolated within each instance and knowing nothing of the other instance, **3)** the "CLR enabled" setting is slightly misleading in that it only governs _user_ Assemblies and _not_ CLR functionality altogether; several components of SQL Server rely on SQLCLR and are not affected by the "clr enabled" setting. AND, please do not cross-post on DBA.SE: the people that would help you there are mostly already involved here or will at least see this.

Comment: @SolomonRutzky Thank you for your time. Unfortunately i don't have access to the 2008 instance. Now that you say that they are isolated, this has become harder to understand.
I'm going to try to replicate this issue in my computer.

Comment: I am echoing @SolomonRutzky here; what does the log-files show, especially the ones from the third party ERP?